# How memory allocation has been done for below scenario? I have managed to muddle it

Tags: c#, memory-management, stack, clr, heap-memory

I have below mention property class with name as **"Employee"**.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public int DeptId { get; set; }
}
```

We all know that **"int"** data type will be store in stack and Object type will be store in heap like as below snap.

[image]

Here my question is, When I am going to create an object of **Employee** class like

```
Employee objEmployee = new Employee();
```

How memory allocation has been done?

Any literature or related link would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> We all know that "int" data type will be store in stack and Object type will be store in heap like as below snap.

Since that is *completely false*, we do not *all know that*.

Think about it:

```
int[] M() { return new int[] { 1 }; }
```

Is the 1 on the stack?  If so, then how can it be accessed from M's caller after M returns?

Obviously it cannot be. The 1 is on the heap even though it is an int.

Your problem is that you're thinking of values, not variables. A variable is storage, regardless of whether there is an integer or a reference stored in it. That storage has to be somewhere. **Where that storage is depends on the lifetime requirement.**  Short term storage can be allocated off the short term storage pool -- stack or registers. Long term storage is allocated off the long term storage pool -- the heap.  It has **nothing whatsoever** to do with whether the value being stored is a struct or a reference.

In your example the backing store for the properties can live arbitrarily long, and therefore must be allocated off the heap.

You need to simply stop believing the myth that values of value types go on the stack.  Values go in *storage*, and *storage goes where it needs to go to fulfill its lifetime requirements*.

Answer (score -1):

`Employee` in your example is a reference type. It placed in Heap and in stack you have only `reference` to it. No matter what fields are inside this class

I suggest you [this article by Joseph Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) to see the difference between value and reference types